# Using the Visitor Pattern with template derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, c++11, visitor-pattern

I try to implement the Visitor pattern with templated derived classes

## **I work with gcc 4.5**

here is the VisitorTemplate.hpp, I specialized Derived in the class Visitor, but I'd like to be able to handle any type:

edit : thanks to the suggestions of interjay, the code compiles and runs without errors now

```cpp
#ifndef VISITORTEMPLATE_HPP_
#define VISITORTEMPLATE_HPP_

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<class T> Derived;

class Visitor
{
  public:
    virtual void visit(Derived<string> *e) = 0;
};

class Base
{
  public:
    virtual void accept(class Visitor *v) = 0;
};

template<class T>
Derived: public Base
{
  public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor *v)
    {
       v->visit(this);
    }
    string display(T arg)
    {
       string s = "This is : " + to_string(arg);
       return s;
    }
};

class UpVisitor: public Visitor
{
   virtual void visit(Derived<string> *e)
   {
     cout << "do Up on " + e->display("test") << '\n';
   }
};

class DownVisitor: public Visitor
{
   virtual void visit(Derived<string> *e)
   {
     cout << "do Down on " + e->display("test") << '\n';
   }
};

#endif /* VISITORTEMPLATE_HPP_ */
```

main.cpp

```cpp
Base* base = new Derived<string>();
Visitor* up = new UpVisitor();
Visitor* down = new DownVisitor();
base->accept(up);
base->accept(down);
```

Now my goal is to use Derived in visit without specializing; unfortunately, visit is a virtual method so I can't template it

Comment: What compiler are you using? I just fed your example code to Visual C++ 2010 and it compiled quite happily, apart from complaining that std::to_string can't handle the template parameter argument type. I can't see any reason in your example code why it would complain about an incomplete type, as you didn't miss out providing implementations for the single pure virtual function.

Comment: @MatthewWalton: "I work with gcc 4.5." However, it's always nice to indicate the lines compiler messages refer to. I don't want to count 31 lines in my browser.

Comment: @sbi doh, I must've forgotten that when I was feeding my compiler the code. Still, I wouldn't think that particular kind of error is the kind that GCC and VC++ would disagree on.

Comment: ok, forget my code, have you an idea to handle this generic Vistor problem ?

Comment: Interesting. It seems that forward declaration of the `class` doesn't go quite hand in hand with `template`s

Answer (score 11):

From Modern C++ - Design Generic Programming and Design Patterns Applied - Andrei Alexandrescu

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseVisitor
{
    public:
        virtual ~BaseVisitor() {};
};

template <class T, typename R = int>
class Visitor
{
    public:
        virtual R visit(T &) = 0;
};

template <typename R = int>
class BaseVisitable
{
    public:
        typedef R ReturnType;
        virtual ~BaseVisitable() {};
        virtual ReturnType accept(BaseVisitor & )
        {
            return ReturnType(0);
        }
    protected:
        template <class T>
        static ReturnType acceptVisitor(T &visited, BaseVisitor &visitor)
        {
            if (Visitor<T> *p = dynamic_cast< Visitor<T> *> (&visitor))
            {
                return p->visit(visited);
            }
            return ReturnType(-1);
        }

        #define VISITABLE() \
            virtual ReturnType accept(BaseVisitor &v) \
                { return acceptVisitor(*this, v); }
};


/** example of use */
class Visitable1 : public BaseVisitable<int>
{
    /* Visitable accept one BaseVisitor */
    public:
        VISITABLE();
};

class Visitable2 : public BaseVisitable<int>
{
    /* Visitable accept one BaseVisitor */
    public:
        VISITABLE();
};

class VisitorDerived : public BaseVisitor,
        public Visitor<Visitable1, int>,
        public Visitor<Visitable2, int>
{
    public:
        int visit(Visitable1 & c)
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }
        int visit(Visitable2 & c)
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    VisitorDerived visitor;
    Visitable1 visitable1;
    Visitable2 visitable2;

    visitable1.accept(visitor);
    visitable2.accept(visitor);
}
```

Is possible to avoid dynamic_cast with CRTP pattern like:

```
#include <iostream>

class BaseVisitor
{
    public:
        virtual ~BaseVisitor() {};
};

template <class T>
class Visitor
{
    public:
        virtual void visit(T &) = 0;
};

template <class Visitable>
class BaseVisitable
{ 
    public:
        template <typename T>
        void accept(T & visitor)
        {
            visitor.visit(static_cast<Visitable &>(*this));
        }
};

/** example of use */
class Visitable1 : public BaseVisitable<Visitable1>
{
};

class Visitable2 : public BaseVisitable<Visitable2>
{
};

class VisitorDerived : public BaseVisitor, 
                       public Visitor<Visitable1>,
                       public Visitor<Visitable2>
{
    public:
        void visit(Visitable1 & c)
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }
        void visit(Visitable2 & c)
        {
            std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    VisitorDerived visitor;
    Visitable1 visitable1;
    Visitable2 visitable2;

    visitable1.accept<VisitorDerived>(visitor);
    visitable2.accept<VisitorDerived>(visitor);
}
```

Comment: I find it a little complicated; is it possible to avoid the dynamic_cast ?

Comment: Yes, you can use CRTP pattern like:

Comment: How would you extend this to cover hierarchies, e.g. DerivedVisitable1, while keeping the static_cast?  Is it possible without changing to the cyclic implementation?

Comment: How could this code be changed to allow for a container of BaseVisitables. Using the first example, I could have an "std::vector<BaseVisitable>", but I can't for the second since the BaseVisitable is templated.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Derived` class cannot use `Visitor` because it hasn't been defined yet (it was only forward declared, and is therefore an incomplete type).

You can fix the compile error by putting the `Visitor` definition before `Derived`. You will also need to forward-declare `Derived` before defining `Visitor`:

```
template <class T> class Derived;

class Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(Derived<string> *e) = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Derived : public Base {
    //.... can call Visitor methods here ...
};
```