# Inteface classes for generic application of visitor pattern

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, interface, visitor-pattern

I faced a problem that could be solved with the visitor pattern, and because I love reusable code I thought it might be a good idea to have some classes that already do most of the magic for me and which I could reuse later. So what I wanted was something like a Visitor class and a Visitable class, from which I can derive to prepare my deriving class for the use of the visitor pattern. I came up with this code:

```
template <typename ret = void>
class Visitor
{
public:
    typedef ret ReturnType;

protected:
    Visitor() {}
    ~Visitor() {}
};

template <typename BaseType>
class Visitable
{
public:
    template <typename Visitor>
    typename Visitor::ReturnType applyVisitor(Visitor& visitor)
    {
        return visitor(static_cast<BaseType*>(this));
    }

    template <typename Visitor>
    typename Visitor::ReturnType applyVisitor(Visitor& visitor) const
    {
        return visitor(static_cast<BaseType*>(this));
    }

protected:
    Visitable() {}
    ~Visitable() {}
};

template <typename VisitorType, typename VisitableType>
inline typename VisitorType::ReturnType applyVisitor(VisitorType visitor, VisitableType visitable)
{
    return visitable->applyVisitor(visitor);
}

class Base : public Visitable <Base>
{
public:
    virtual void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "BASE" << std::endl;
    };

    std::string foobar() const
    {
        return "BASE";
    };
};

class Derived : public Base, public Visitable<Derived>
{
public:
    using Visitable<Derived>::applyVisitor;

    void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "DERIVED" << std::endl;
    }; 

    std::string bar() const
    {
        return "DERIVED";
    };
};

struct MyVisitor : public Visitor < >
{
    template <class T>
    void operator()(T const var) const
    {
        var->foo();
    }
};

struct MyOtherVisitor : public Visitor <std::string>
{
    std::string operator()(Base * const var) const
    {
        return var->foobar();
    }

    std::string operator()(Derived * const var) const
    {
        return var->bar();
    }
};

int main(int _Argc, char* _Argv)
{
    Base *pVirtualDerived = new Derived();
    Base *pBase = new Base();
    Derived *pDerived = new Derived();

    std::cout << "Member method:" << std::endl;

    applyVisitor(MyVisitor(), pVirtualDerived);
    applyVisitor(MyVisitor(), pBase);
    applyVisitor(MyVisitor(), pDerived);

    std::cout << std::endl << "External method:" << std::endl;

    std::cout << applyVisitor(MyOtherVisitor(), pVirtualDerived) << std::endl;
    std::cout << applyVisitor(MyOtherVisitor(), pBase) << std::endl;
    std::cout << applyVisitor(MyOtherVisitor(), pDerived) << std::endl;
}
```

As one might already guess from the names I was inspired by [boost::static_visitor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/static_visitor.html) and [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html). However, one can also notice that my implementation is flawed in two aspects:

1. It does not suffice to just inherit from Visitable, I also need to put a using declaration into my class to resolve ambiguity for the `applyVisitor` method.
2. It is not really the visitor pattern. Calling `applyVisitor` with a `Base*` that actually points to a `Derived` object does not call `Derived::foo` but `Base::foo`. I cannot declare `applyVisitor` in `Visitable<T>` virtual because it is a templated method. But I need the template because `Visitor<T>` is a template class it self and I would like to keep the generic return type for my visitors.

Long story short, can I somehow solve both problems and end up with two classes from which I simply need to derive to prepare my code for the visitor pattern?

Comment: does it have to be your own implementation or could you use other libraries? [The Loki library](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/html/a00559.html) has a generic implementation for Visitor.

Comment: I was thinking whether CRTP could be a solution and found this: http://shanhe.me/2011/08/06/curiously-recurring-template-pattern-and-visitor-implementation-in-cpp-java and http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877397/104774 Do these help with your problem?

Comment: I already use the CRTP technique here, however the example code from your link only supports fixed return types, but I want to support any return type.
The other example seems to be based on the implementation of the Loki library. So I will have a look into this.

Comment: I'm not here because of C++ but because it's a Visitor question. Here's how it was done in Java (hope this is useful): http://musingsofaprogrammingaddict.blogspot.ca/2009/01/visitor-pattern-generic-and-still-type.html

Comment: @MatthiasB : Unfortunately it looks like that the constructs from the Loki library do not apply to my case. They can't handle inheritance.

Comment: @stefaanv : The other example does not work with inheritance and furthermore the visitables need to know the return type of their visitors.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator : In this example the visitables need to know of all visitors, this is not really maintainable code

Comment: 'this is not really maintainable code' -- why do you say that? The assumption of the Visitor problem is that Visitors are things that need maintaining. Visitibles are supposed to be stable (it's an assumption of the pattern). A visitor *does something* to or with the visitables, so it must *know* what they are. Can you provide a real example of a problem where a visitor doesn't concretely know what it's visiting?

Comment: No, I was talking of the opposite. In the code you provided the Visitable needed to know about all concrete Visitors. So each time I need a new Visitor I would need to edit my Visitables. In my example I want the Visitables to be in my library, but the Visitors should be user defined. So I am looking for an interface that allows my Visitables to be accessed by all kinds of Visitors. And I don't want to touch the code of my Visitables when a client of my library needs another kind of Visitor.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things to talk about Visitor Design Patterns and C++ inheritance. In the specific case that you described, I think the solutions are:

About the first problem, since the Base class is already inheriting from Visitable, you don't need to inherit from it again in the derived class:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void foo() const
    {
        std::cout << "DERIVED" << std::endl;
    };
};
```

About the second problem, I think you just forgot the virtual keyword in the Base class:

```
class Base : public Visitable<Base>
{
    public:
        virtual void foo() const
        {
            std::cout << "BASE" << std::endl;
        };
};
```

Comment: My example code did not show this, so I updated it accordingly, but I think I need both classes to derive from Visitable in order for the static_cast to work (almost) probably in case I need to call different methods depending on the actual type.
For this reason my example code was a bit silly because what I did there could already be done with simple polymorphism.