# Cannot overload base class method in derived class in C++

Tags: c++, methods, overloading, base-class

**What I am trying to do**

I am converting an existing code base which uses dynamic_casting to identify the derived class (shape) to apply derived class specific processing, to a scheme which is based on the visitor pattern. To this effect, I have added a processMe method to the base class (virtual) and in each derived class and a handleShape method to a ShapeProcessor class, one for each type of shape to be processed, typical of the visitor pattern. I have a ShapeProcessor abstract base class that has one pure virtual method that forces the user to provide a catch all shape processor and allows the user to derive from the ShapeProcessor and add other shape processing methods as desired (e.g. MyShapeProcessor : public ShapeProcessor)

**Observation**

However what find is that only the catch all method gets called in MyShapeProcessor for all shapes, my shape specific methods are not getting called. What do I need to do to get the shape specific methods to get called as desired? Caveat: If I put all handler methods in one class, it works fine. Does this mean that it is not possible to overload methods in the base class? I have read the posts on name hiding, but that does not seem to apply here. Or does it? I tried to unhide the base class method using "using" but does not seem to help.

Here is the pseudo code example:

```
class Shape {
    virtual void processMe (ShapeProcessor * sp) {
        sp->processShape (*this);
}

// User derived shape
class Circle : public Shape {
    void processMe (ShapeProcessor * sp) {
        sp->processShape (*this);
}

// Base ShapeProcessor
class ShapeProcessor {
    virtual void processShape (Shape& shape) = 0; // User must provide a catch all method
}

// User provided shape processor
class MyShapeProcessor : public ShapeProcessor {
    void processShape (Circle& circle) {
       // Never gets called, even for Circle objects!
    }
    void processShape (Shape& shape) {
       // Always gets called for all shapes!
       cout << "Unsupported shape!" << endl;
    }
}

// User code
Circle * circle = new Circle();
MyShapeProcessor * sp = new MyShapeProcessor();
circle->processMe (sp);  

// Expecting processMe to eventually call MyShapeProcessor processShape (Circle) but calls processShape (Shape)

// Caveat: If I get rid of the ShapeProcessor base class and if I put all shape handles in a single class
// it works fine. Does this mean that it is not possible to overload methods in the base class? I have read
// the posts on name hiding, but that does not seem to apply here. Or does it?
```

Comment: I would recommend that, before you go any further, you pick out a programming language to use.

Comment: Thanks, I have added C++ in the tags and in the title. I hope that is all I need to do? (I am an infrequent poster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
void processShape (Circle& circle);
```

to `ShapeProcessor` as a `virtual` member function. Without that, this function is not visible from any of the `processMe` functions.

```
class ShapeProcessor {
    virtual void processShape (Shape& shape) = 0;

    virtual void processShape (Circle& circle) = 0;

};
```

When you add a new sub-type of `Shape` in your project, you have to come back to `ShapeProcessor` and add a new `processShape` function for the sub-type.

You can use templates to avoid some of this tight coupling. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7877397/434551.

Comment: You have two functions named `processShape(Shape&)`.

Comment: I see. If I do that though, that is defeating the intent to provide a bare ShapeProcessor class and allow the user to provide their own MyShapeProcessor classes. What I want to do is to enforce that the users provide a default handler but not require any more code in the base class.

Comment: @kman - That is the downside to visitor.  The visitor base class must have a virtual method for each possible derived type because the processMe methods only have the base ShapeProcessor to work with.  The caller must see an overload for each derived type so it knows which virtual method to call.  This makes the Visitor a very tightly-coupled pattern which works well if your class hierarchy doesn't change much.

Comment: That's part of the visitor pattern.  The reason you provide the method processShape(Circle&) is because Circle is going to call it with itself--i.e., with an object whose derived type is Circle.  If you don't provide this signature in the base class which is virtual, you don't really have a virtual override in your MyProcessShape class; all you get is a call to processShape(Shape&) with an implicit cast of Circle& to Shape&, which defeats the entire purpose of the visitor.

Comment: Understood, and thanks. It appears that Visitor is not the right way to solve my problem. I will select the Answer.

Comment: @kman That's the way Visitor works. If you want a default generic processor, make ShapeProcessor::processShape(Circle&) call processShape(Shape&). The user can override either method.

Comment: @RSahu Thanks for the template link. Yes, I had thought of that too, however unfortunately, my framework has some existing derived classes which need to be supported and in addition, users can develop their own derived classes. The template derived class will not work for existing derived classes from the framework as it basically changes the type.

Answer (score 0):

Would this approach also suit you??

```
#include <iostream>


class Shape;


class ShapeProcessor {
public:
    virtual void processShape(Shape &shape){
        std::cout<<"Shape Processor";
    }
};

class CircleProcessor: public ShapeProcessor {

public:
    void processShape(Shape &shape)
    {
        std::cout<<"CircleProcessor";
    }
};
class  Shape
{
public:

    virtual void processMe(ShapeProcessor *sp){
        sp->processShape(*this);
    }
};
class Circle:public Shape
{
public:
    void processMe(ShapeProcessor *sp){
        sp->processShape(*this);
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Shape  *circle = new Circle();
    ShapeProcessor *sp = new CircleProcessor();
    circle->processMe(sp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not really, unless I misunderstood. I need to implicitly detect the type of shape and take different actions. If I already knew the type of the shape (to create a shape specific processor), this problem would be moot. Perhaps my example was confusing.